# Concourse CI input as folder to pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, task, pipeline, concourse

How do I pass a folder to a pipeline with custom code?
To elaborate I have few scripts in a folder (I am aware that this has to go to git) and this folder needs to be passed as input to a task to run the script

Have added inputs : [Current DIR Name】in the tasks.yml and works fine if I run fly through fly execute command.

But if I add this task to a pipeline and run though fly set-pipeline the folder does not get uploaded/added to container. Error message : Missing inputs (fol-name)

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1):

In your build plan, make sure you `get` the resource your folder is in before you run your task. The basic idea is that resources can be mounted as inputs in your task. Here's a small exampe:

```
resources:
- name: your-folder
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git://git.example.com/your/folder.git
    branch: master

jobs:
- name: your-job
  plan:
  - get: your-folder
  - task: do-work
    file: task.yml
```